# How to get custom inflected class working with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two class:

```rb
class DataGeneratingModule < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :action_coordinates
end

class ActionCoordinates < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SingleTableInheritable

  has_and_belongs_to_many :data_generating_modules
end
```

`ActionCoordinates` is intentionally always plural here. It doesn't make sense within the domain to have it singular

So I created a custom inflector

```rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
 inflect.irregular 'action_coordinates', 'action_coordinates'
end
```

When I then call `DataGeneratingModule.first.action_coordinates`

I get an errorr

```
NameError (uninitialized constant DataGeneratingModule::ActionCoordinate)
```

If you notice it is looking for the class definition with the singular `ActionCoordinate`

Although it appears that the custom inflector is working, the instance method exists, however it seems to not be applying the inflector when looking for the class definition.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like I shouldn't have to do this here but I had to specify the class name:

`has_and_belongs_to_many :action_coordinates, class_name: "ActionCoordinates"`